# $\text{rank}(AB)=\text{rank}(B)$ implication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Suppose $ABC = ABD$ and $\text{rank}(AB) = \text{rank}(B)$.

It is said that $\text{rank}(AB) =\text{rank}(B)$ would imply $B = EAB$.

However, I fail to understand this implication as I understand that the rank gives us information about the dimension of column/rank space but not the values in the matrix.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @user593721: You should provide more information. In particular, what is $E$? Also, when you say "It is said .  . .", you should give a reference. Is the problem from a book? If so, which book, which problem? The additional information should be included as part of your post.

Comment: E is just another matrix.  It is not a problem of a book but part of the answer that was given which I do not understand

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be the image of $B$ and $W$ the image of $AB$. We are given that $\dim U=\dim W$ and conclude that $A|_U\colon U\to W$ is an isomorphism. Let $E$ be the inverse of $A$ on $W$ and arbitrary on a complement of $W$. Then $EAB=B$.